# Using Patch method ,not updating record(curd operation)

Tags: php, laravel-5

**i have successfuly inserted,read and deleted the record while 
    performing Basic CURD operation.Now i am trying to update/edit record
    which is successfully inserted in database.But the record is not 
    updating after clicking the update button,It shows the previous record as it is**

route.php

```
Route::get("edit/{id}" , "testing@edit");
Route::patch("update/{id}" , "testing@update");
```

testing.php

```
// this is  edit function

public function edit($id)
{
    $user=curd::find($id);
    return view("update",compact("user"));
}

// this is update function


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = curd::find($id);
    $user->update(Request::all());
    return redirect("read");
}
```

update.blade.php

```
 <html>
  <head>

      <title>update</title>
  </head>
<body>
<!-- Here We Use Patch Method  !-->

{{Form::model($user,['method'=>'patch', 'action'=> 
['testing@update',$user->id]])}}

{{Form::label('name','name')}}
{{Form::text('Name')}}

{{Form::submit('Update')}}
{{Form::close()}}


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are using patch in updating contents ?

due to laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing)

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when
>   defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML
>   form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The
>   value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request
>   method

and due to more resources about why does PUT,DELETE,PUSH is not allowed in `<form>` tag.

I think [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/114169/201285) is more simple to get why exactly form tag allows only GET,POST HTTP requests

> GET and POST have a clear content-neutral rationale. GET is to
>   retrieve the content of an URL in a way that is safe to repeat and
>   possibly cache. POST is to do something in a way that is not safe to
>   repeat, execute speculatively, or cache.
>
> There was no similar rationale for PUT or DELETE. They are both
>   completely covered by POST. Creating or destroying a resource are
>   operations that are not safe to repeat, not safe to execute
>   speculatively, and should not be cached. There are no additional
>   special semantics needed for them.
>
> So basically there is no benefit.

Comment: I am still facing this problem ,update function is not updating record,it still shows previous record as it is.